# number not getting added and printed in for loop

Tags: javascript, node.js

i testing some codes, and i need a logic for my program, but i tested in a separated arquive and i got the following problem:

```
let numero = 0;
const string = `aaa: ${numero}`

for(let i=0; i<3;i++) {
  console.log(string)
  numero += 1
}

console.log(numero)
```

but the result is this:

```
aaa: 1
aaa: 1
aaa: 1
4
```

- why the loop are adding , but in string continue with the value of 1?

someone can explain what is my error? javascript is really weird some times xD

Comment: The value of a string is not dynamic. Even if the value of `numero` changes, the value of the string will not.

Comment: Move ```const string = `aaa: ${numero}` ``` inside the loop.

Answer (score 1):

write string = `aaa: ${numero}` after for(let i=0; i<3;i++)

The reason its doing that is because numero changes in the for loop but the string is declared outside of the for loop and is therefore constant.

Comment: thanks! i undestood :)! its worked!!

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this behaviour - scope. When you use console.log into loop you get numero from global scope that = 0.

Just use follow code:

```js
let numero = 0;
const string = 'aaa: ';

for(let i=0; i<3;i++) {
  console.log(string + numero);
  numero += 1
}

console.log(numero)
```

Comment: ohh thankss! i saw the problem, your solution is better and dynamic, thank youu!

Answer (score 0):

For two reasons:

In your case specifically: You are assigning the value *outside your loop* that means that `string` is assigned only once, so it will never change.

Moreover `string` is a constant and technically shouldn't change (there are exceptions, for example when your constant is an object or an array). If you try to change it (inside the loop) you will get an error. Instead of `const` use `let`, because you want to change it.

```
let numero = 0;
let string = `aaa: ${numero}`

for(let i=0; i<3;i++) {
  console.log(string)
  numero += 1
  string += 1
}

console.log(numero)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you set the `string` variable it is using a string literal which only uses the value of `numero` when you created it - which is `0`.
It doesn't dynamically update itself. You have set it equal again to a new value;

You have 2 options

1. Change the `string` from `const` to `let` so you can change its value, and update the value of the `string` variable within the for loop like this:

```
let numero = 0;
let string = `aaa: ${numero}`;

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    string = `aaa: ${numero}`;
    console.log(string);
    numero += 1;
}

console.log(numero)
```

2. Create a function that returns the updated string every time it's called inside the for loop, like this:

```
let numero = 0;

function updateString() {
    return `aaa: ${numero}`;
}

for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    console.log(updateString());
    numero += 1;
}

console.log(numero);
```